# Cygwin color appering ANSI codes (for example: ←[0;34;1m)

Tags: cygwin

I running Avrora simulation for tinyOS application using cygwin. But the colors are appearing as the underlying ANSI codes (for example: `←[0;34;1m`).

I experience the problem on Windows7 32-bit. I can see colors if I do something like `ls --color`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably Avrora is not a Cygwin program, and you're using the default Cygwin console. Cygwin does support ANSI colour codes in the console, as you saw with `ls --color`, but only for Cygwin programs, i.e. those linked against the Cygwin DLL. Non-Cygwin programs just see a standard Windows console, which does not support ANSI codes.

You should be able to get this working, however, by using one of the alternative Cygwin terminals such as mintty or xterm.